# Whitelabel Django Application and connecting Google and Facebook accounts

Tags: django, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, white-labelling, google-business-profile-api

We have a web application that runs on say **domain.com**.  We then have whitelabel users that access the application from **subdomain.theirdomain.com**.

Our application is able to **connect Google, Facebook, Twitter** accounts using our main domain (domain.com) and our integration with each platform.

But when whitelabel users want to connect the process shows the name of our application and **redirects to our domain** (breaking whitelabel).

We are looking at **creating a generic application** on each platform (google, facebook etc) for our whitelabel users on **generic domain xyz-connector.com** with a generic name and logo.

However the **users are not logged in on that domain** so when the platform redirects to that domain after the user has successfully gone through the authorization\connection process **we cannot associate the connection with the user**.

We need to know which account has just authenticated so we can update the database.

Using Django 3.1.

Ideally we want our users to connect\authenticate their accounts directly from their white labeled subdomain or domain. Rather than having to login to xyz-connector.com.

Can we share sessions?  Or do these services (facebook, google) allow us to pass custom variables they will pass back to us when connecting that we can use to associate the users account?

Is there a best practice for achieving this?

Comment: The `state` parameter is the only one Facebook allows to be "dynamic", so you can put any information you need after return to your app, in there. (It's main purpose is CSRF protection though, it might be a good idea to still use it for that as well. You can f.e. pass a JSON structure that contains a random state for the CSRF protection purposes, and whatever else you need along with it.) Google probably has a similar mechanism.

Comment: thanks @CBroe .. that seems to be the way to go. Should most social services support this (facebook, google, twitter etc)